# RegularExpressionValidator returning NULL with invalid input

Tags: c#, validation

I have the following code:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{8}", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
public string PhoneHome { get; set; }
```

If I input asdf, I get modelState.valid == true and PhoneHome == null

What I want is the getting the ErrorMessage and modelState.valid == false when the phone number is not either blank or 8 numbers.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are just saying that if something is there it must fit that regular expression. To make it a requirement you need to add the required field:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{8}", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
public string PhoneHome { get; set; }
```

Not sure but you may be able to use (depends on version):

```
[Required, RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{8}", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
public string PhoneHome { get; set; }
```

Comment: I would urge you to read the question again. Phone number is NOT required. But if it is filled inn, it should be 8 numbers exact. The problem is that with my current code, "ASDF" does not mark it as a invalid, it simply sets the model = NULL.

Comment: @devzero sorry reread it and I can see why my answer is unhelpful.

I don't think there is a direct method as I don't believe there is a null/blank regex that works and if the field is not required the incorrect input will just be ignored instead of setting an invalid state.

I would do it by making it required then by removing PhoneHome from the modelState on the return if it is null/blank.

Comment: Seems like the problem was Angular JS validation and not C# validation. The problem is exactly the same, but Angular is the culprit, not MVC, as it modifies the form before sending it to MVC so that it seemed like the validation removed the value.